# How to get widget id another application?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, widget, action

Code is written as follows:

```
Intent widget = new Intent(
        "test.widgets.Widget1x2");
widget.setAction("android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE");

ComponentName name = new ComponentName(
        "test.widgets", "Widget1x2");

int[] ids = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context)
        .getAppWidgetIds(name);
```

I  have get Ids widgets application test.widgets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use it this way:

```
AppWidgetManager manager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
int[] ids = manager.getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName(context,
                Widget1x2.class));
```

This should work.